# Is it possible to create turtles of square shape proportional to x% of world surface area or size in Netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

I wanted to initialise my world with turtles that would theoretically occupy x% of the total surface area or the size of the world. How do I know what is the exact size of each turtle? I know the world size can be calculated by:

```
world-width
world-height
```

My turtles are triangular in size and currently a size 4 and as per patch size 5 and dimensions of the world set to -80 80 -80 80, this size is perfect and I would like to keep it at size 4.

How do I calculate what number of turtles would occupy 1%, 5%, 10%, 20% and 40% of the entire surface area?

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track with [`world-width` and `world-size`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#world-dim).  Those give you the size of the world, based on the number of patches.

If you want to make a turtle to have half the surface area, you just need to update it's [`size` variable](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#size), which is also measured in patches.  So a turtle with `size` of 1 is exactly as tall and wide as a single patch.

```
to make-half-size-square
  clear-all
  ; assumes we want a square shape, just use `sqrt` on the total world surface area
  let half-surface-size sqrt (world-width * world-height / 2)
  show half-surface-size
  crt 1 [
    set shape "square"
    set size half-surface-size
  ]
end

to make-half-size-circle
  clear-all
  ; assumes we want a circle shape
  let half-surface-size 2 * sqrt ((world-width * world-height / 2) / pi)
  show half-surface-size
  crt 1 [
    set shape "circle"
    set size half-surface-size
  ]
end
```

A couple extra bits of info, though:

1. The `size` only controls the visual size of the turtle in the world view.  It still only lives on a single patch.  If you want to get all turtles/patches "under" the turtle shape you'll need to use `in-radius` (for a circle) or do a bounding-box check using the turtle's `size` (for a square).
2. The turtle might not quite appear to take up half the surface area.  This is because the shape the turtle uses might not go all the way to the edge of its possible size.  Even the `square` shape that comes with NetLogo doesn't quite have its edges all the way at the end, but the `circle` does.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding. I actually wanted to create many turtles but their combined surface area to be half of the world's surface area. How can I do that? Currently they are triangles, and their size is set to 4 because this size is perfect for my visualisation and they occupy maximum dimernsions in the tuirtles shapes editor.

I am using patch size 5, and world width and world height is showing as 161 and 161 each right now.

I want to initialise a turtle population that would occupy 1%, 5%, 10%, 20% and 40% of the total surface area available.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried counting the total number of patches and dividing them by size of my triangles, and then multiplying that number by 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2 and 0.4 to see how many triangles I need to create but the number is way off.